# Traversing through each directory to identify file types and the count of each type?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to build a script that can help me in traversing through all the files in a directory and to identify its file type. At the end the result should print the total count of each file type that were identified. I am using the [`magic`](https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic) library to identify the file type based on MIME.

```
for filename in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    print filename
    with magic.Magic(flags=magic.MAGIC_MIME_TYPE) as m:
        t = m.id_filename(filename)
        print t
```

The identification piece is pasted above which seems to be working fine but I am not sure how to store the identified filetypes and their count. The output should look like:
filetype1 count
filetype2 count
...
...

Please guide me as to what should be the ideal way of doing it.

Comment: throw all your filenames into a list `new_list`, and `from collections import Counter` to `Counter(new_list)`

Comment: and by filenames I meant file types :P

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dictionary containing a mapping of each file type to its count. e.g.

```
file_types = {'filetype1' : 10, 'filetype2': 20, ...}
```

Note that your current solution will only work on the current directory and not subdirectories.

```
file_types = {}

for filename in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    with magic.Magic(flags=magic.MAGIC_MIME_TYPE) as m:
        t = m.id_filename(filename)
        file_types.setdefault(t, 0)
        file_types[t] += 1
...
```

Should append and count for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class from the `collections` module. It is basically a variant of a dictionary, with a few additional methods and the advantage that you don't need to initialize it with `0` when counting.

I don't have that `magic` that you mention, so here's an example using `my_magic` as a substitute:

```py
import collections
import os

def my_magic(filename):
    """
    This function is just a placeholder to be used in place of your id_filename()
    method.
    """
    if filename.endswith(".txt"): 
        return "TXT"
    elif filename.endswith(".pdf"):
        return "PDF"
    else:
        return "other"

# initialize the counter object:
counter = collections.Counter()

for filename in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    print filename

    # substitute the next line with whatever you use to determine the 
    # type of the file:
    t = my_magic(filename)
    print t

    # increase the count for the current value of 't':
    counter[t] += 1

# output what is in counter:
for ext, n in counter.items():
    print ext, n
```